I tried using nested Inkwell function in flutter but only one inkwell working
I need for certain use nested inkwell and need to add separate function onTap. How should  I make it work.
Please find a sample code here-
   InkWell(
        onTap: () => print("1st inkwell"),
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () => print("2nd inkwell"),
          child: Icon(Icons.close),
        ),
      ),


wow,what are you trying to achive?why?are not getting good results on just  calling two functions/methods??

just need sort of this function for some custom widget

those two inkwells has the same size and position - there is no point to use them in such case

Try below code hope its help:
InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          print("You have tapped InkWell");
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              print("You have tapped GestureDetector");
            },
            behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
          ).onTap?.call();
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.close),
      ),

I have try using HitTestBehavior, Read more about GestureTapCallback

This is working. Thanks

Glad to help you. enjoy your ride with Flutter.

no, no, no, it has nothing to do with tapping GestureDetector, run this simple code on https://dartpad.dev and you will see why: void main() { Foo( onTap: () { print("You have tapped Foo, really?"); }, ).onTap.call(); }  class Foo { Foo({required this.onTap}); final Function() onTap; }

Use GestureDetector and set behavior to HitTestBehavior.translucent to allow the tap to be passed to the child.
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () => print("1st inkwell"),
  behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
  child: InkWell(
    onTap: () => print("2nd inkwell"),
    child: Icon(Icons.close),
  ),
)


tried this but not working. only prints 2ndinkwell

When you nest InkWell widgets, the inner InkWell typically captures the tap gesture. This means that the outer InkWell might not receive the tap event if the inner one is absorbing it.
So use GestureDetector with InkWell. Replace your first Inkwell with GestureDetector
GestureDetector(
   onTap:()=>print("1st click"),
   child:Container(
         child:Inkwell(
         onTap:()=>print("2nd click");
         child:Icon(Icons.close) 
        )
    )
)

I have tried with IgnorePointer, check if it helps you
     InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            print('Outer InkWell tapped');
          },
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    print('Inner InkWell tapped');
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                    child: Text('Tap Me'),
                  ),
                ),
                IgnorePointer(
                  ignoring: true,
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.transparent,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text('Another layer'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),


tried doing this but still not working. Thank you for answer though.

Code edited with IgnorePointer, hope it helps...

Thanks @DroidFlutter but it wont work. this i want in my custom floating action button, in which if we click any action button the expanded fab shoudl close.
